# Schematic for Ford IASF Regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, alternator

Where can I find the *internal* schematic for the common Ford external alternator regulator, the one with **`I A S F`** terminals? I believe these type regulators were very common in the '80s.

And also the internal wiring diagram for the alternator that went along with it (model ??).

What would be a good vehicle make and model to give a parts counter guy when ordering one of these?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the 4 pin diagram, it has never changed over the years for external regulators.

A= Battery, to alt and battery.

I= Charging indicator on instrument cluster

F= Field (alt)

S= Stator (Alt)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was really hoping to see the inner workings of the regulator. I would have expected this information to be easy to find on the internet. Not so.

Comment: They are electronic now, the old ones had mechanical coils.

Comment: If you research old regulators for generators, they are similar in operation.

Comment: Basics>>>>https://itstillruns.com/automotive-voltage-regulator-work-5024418.html

Comment: I would like to see the electronic schematic for the regulator. It would give me flexibility to use it in non-standard setups.

Comment: I have never found any, sorry. Depending on manufacturer what electronics they used to get the job done.

Comment: Do you have a diagram for the old mechanical job? Maybe I can deduce from it how the electronic one works.

Comment: I use to, but not any more unfortunately.